# Deploying client specific Scripts using SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, composite, dacpac

I am quite new to SSDT and I want to achieve the following. Would really appreciate if someone could shed some light.

I already have Project within a solution, which deploys a database to clients. I want to be able to deploy a second database using a sqlcmd variable. i.e, if $(customer)='mycustomer', then deploy the second database.

Can I maintain a separate project for this database on the same solution, and how can I package these 2 projects to be deployed in on go?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like something outside of SSDT. I'd manage it in a PS script or batch file to check for the conditions that would drive creating the other database. If they're met, create the DB.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I was going through some of your blogs too. Appreciate your help!